# How can I download more than 5 to 10 GB files in PHP?

Tags: download

what do I have to do if I cant download a file more than 5 to 10 GB files? what PHP or JAVASCRIPT script do I have to use?

Comment: Why can't you download these files? How did you try that? What happens? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: No, nothing but When I download a file, the file is not completely downloaded but its corrupted though. I have a file management system and I need to upload 10 GB files (ZIP FILE) and download it but the download script that I am using now is not good.